# Error inflating class org.xwalk.core.XWalkView

Tags: java, android

I have imported CrossWalkView to my project and I am trying to use it inside my app but when I add the `org.xwalk.core.XWalkView` tag to my `activity` my app crashes

my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SecondActivity"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <org.xwalk.core.XWalkView
        android:id="@+id/xWalkView"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </org.xwalk.core.XWalkView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have implemented the Xwalkview library by adding `flatDir{dirs 'libs'}` to the `top-level gradle` like so:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}
```

and in my app gradle I added `implementation(name:'CrossWalkView', ext:'aar')`

my CrossWalkView.arr file is [xwalk_core_library-23.53.589.4-arm.aar](https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library/23.53.589.4/)

I have tried implementing the CrossWalkView in every way I could find but all resulted in a crash upon opening the `SecondActivity` where I am using the `org.xwalk.core.XWalkView` tag and only when I remove it the activity runs normally and doesn't crash

The complete error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.player.wavenet/com.player.wavenet.SecondActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class org.xwalk.core.XWalkView
```

Comment: Your project isn't reading the aar file. If it *is*, then make sure you are using the correct path of the view. Can you import the view in the activity? If you can't, then the project is definetely *not* reading the aar file.

Answer (score 0):

just remove this line

```
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

from this

```
<org.xwalk.core.XWalkView
        android:id="@+id/xWalkView"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </org.xwalk.core.XWalkView>
```

Comment: I removed this line and still got the same error

Comment: Actually, this has no effect in this case. You can add a namespace to whatever view you want!